# How can I clear all data from data extension using Java fuel sdk API

Tags: data, extension

```
PerformRequestMsg performRequestMsg = new PerformRequestMsg();
performRequestMsg.setAction("ClearData");
PerformRequestMsg.Definitions definitions = new PerformRequestMsg.Definitions();

definitions.getDefinition().add(getDataExtension());
performRequestMsg.setDefinitions(definitions);

PerformResponseMsg responseMsg = etDataExtension.getClient().getSoapConnection().getSoap().perform(performRequestMsg);

System.out.println("Perform ClearData Result = "+ responseMsg.getOverallStatus());
```

getDataExtension just builds the data extension with and Id and CustomerKey

Here is the response:

```
<StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
<StatusMessage>Unable to perform requested operation on DataExtension: Some key Some key 
(this is filled in with GUID), CustomerKey: External Customer key is here.</StatusMessage>
```

Comment: Just hit the same problem, it was working yesterday, but today its throwing this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

```
PerformRequestMsg performRequestMsg = new PerformRequestMsg();
performRequestMsg.setAction("ClearData");
PerformRequestMsg.Definitions definitions = new PerformRequestMsg.Definitions();

ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class, "Name = "+dataExtensionName);
ETResult<ETDataExtension> result = response.getResult();
ETDataExtension dataExtension = result.getObject();

definitions.getDefinition().add(response.getObject().toInternal());
performRequestMsg.setDefinitions(definitions);

PerformResponseMsg responseMsg = dataExtension.getClient().getSoapConnection().getSoap().perform(performRequestMsg);

System.out.println("Perform ClearData Result = "+ responseMsg.getOverallStatus());
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of what you changed and why it fixes the issue so that people who see this answer know how to resolve it going forward?